# how to determine the coordinates of JButton in java

Tags: java

```
public MainFrame() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoolPegia");
    frame.setTitle("Background Color for JFrame");
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("F:\\photosForJava\\unnamed.png"));
    frame.add(background);
    background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton startPlay=new JButton("Start play!");
    startPlay.addActionListener(this);
    startPlay.setBounds(100, 50, 100,50); //here I am trying something, not working
    background.add(startPlay);
    frame.setSize(399,399);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
}
```

I am trying to determine the coordinates of my `startPlay` Button.. this is just not work. 
help?

Comment: The location (and size) of the button will be determined by the layout manager when the container is validated (and laid out). What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I saw you suggested to add background.setLayout(null); . As far as I know default a JLabel uses a null layout , So we don't need to set it to null specially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to set Frame layout , set the label layout to null by removing this line.

```
background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

If you want to know the Button location, you can do it uisng getX() and getY()

```
  System.out.println(startPlay.getX() + ", " + startPlay.getY());
```

Comment: Seriously, how is this any different to what has already been started

Answer (score 0):

To place you controls on frame as per your co-ordinates, you need to set the layout of frame to `null`. Replace following line:

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

to following and try again

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

`Note:` Now you will require to give co-ordinates for each of your controls.

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: If you don't like yourself and like repeating work which has already been done (through numerous layout managers) and love tearing your hair out because it looks awsome only on your computer, sure...

Comment: As near as I can tell, the question is asking "where" the button is. Besides, if some wanted to know how to shoot a gun, would you just point them to the trigger, or teach them proper gun safety?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will change your button's size but not its coordinates, As coordinates are set by it's `LayoutManager` i.e. `FlowLayout()` of background.

```
startPlay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,30));
```

**Extra:** Layout is recommended because when frame is re-sized LayoutManager will adjust the components accordingly. If you do `setLayout(null)`, You are saying user should not re-size frame for this `setResizable(false)` a non-responsive UI, In my point of view it is only preferable to small and static frame

Answer (score 0):

If it is only th position of the Button you need you can get it by getLocation() and getLocationOnScreen() JButton methods (from Component superclass).

If you want to layout yourself your button, you must set the layout manager to null and set the locations of your componants yourself by setLocation(Point) but it is a bad practice.